# Facade Pattern Not Resolving Bind Property if app isn't initialize

Tags: php, laravel, facade

Currently, I am working on Facade Pattern which doesn't resolve through the application main Container class where i have implement `bind` method through the interface.

- Index.php

```php
use Bundles\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/users', function () {
    return 'Hello';
});
```

Facade:

- Route facade

```php
namespace Bundles\Support\Facades;

class Route extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'route';
    }
}
```

- Facade.php

```php
namespace Bundles\Support\Facades;

use Bundles\Foundations\Application;
use RuntimeException;

class Facade
{
    /**
     * The application instance being facaded.
     */
    protected static Application $app;

    /**
     * The resolved object instances.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $resolvedInstance;

    /**
     * Indicates if the resolved instance should be cached.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected static $cached = true;

    /**
     * @param $method
     * @param $args
     */
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();

        if (!$instance) {
            throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
        }
        var_dump($method, $args, static::getFacadeAccessor());
        Application::$app->bind(static::getFacadeAccessor(), $args, $method);

        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Get the root object behind the facade.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function getFacadeRoot()
    {
        return static::resolveFacadeInstance(static::getFacadeAccessor());
    }

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException('Facade does not implement getFacadeAccessor method.');
    }

    /**
     * Resolve the facade root instance from the container.
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected static function resolveFacadeInstance($name)
    {
        if (isset(static::$resolvedInstance[$name])) {
            return static::$resolvedInstance[$name];
        }

        if (static::$app) {
            if (static::$cached) {
                return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];
            }

            return static::$app[$name];
        }
    }
}
```

- Container.php

```php
namespace Bundles\Containers;

use Bundles\Foundations\Application;
use Bundles\Interfaces\Application as ApplicationContract;
use Bundles\Routes\Route;

class Container implements ApplicationContract
{
    /**
     * @var Route 
     */
    public Route $router;

    /**
     * @var Application
     */
    public static Application $app;

    // register method called in Application constructor
    public function register()
    {
        $this->router = new Route();
    }

    /**
     * > The `bind` function takes a string as the first argument, and a second argument that can be either a string or a
     * closure.
     *
     * @param string abstract The abstract type to bind to
     * @param concrete the class name or a closure that returns an instance of the class
     * @param shared whether the object should be shared or not
     * @param null|mixed $concrete
     * @param mixed      $shared
     */
    public function bind(string $abstract, $concrete = null, $shared = ''): void
    {
        var_dump($abstract, $concrete);

        exit;
    }
}
```

anyone can help on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is this `Bundles` namespace and why are you not just using Laravel's `illuminate` libraries? also Laravel's Facades are not "facade pattern", they are static proxies

Comment: I am customising some of laravel feature as per my requirement so i have created own custom core

Comment: then extend from those libraries and override what you need, you are trying to reinvent the entire vehicle not just the wheel here ... there is nothing functional here in any of this code

Comment: Only issue is i want to resolve the facade from my container bind method but the issue is static::$app is null in my case as I haven't added facades while application mout

Comment: you don't resolve a facade (they resolve their root from the container), and what is calling `bind` to even set that binding? you have no way to store these bindings or resolve anything from the container .... use what Laravel provides, it is already built and functions properly and is tested

Comment: Basically i am hiding complexity of classes. So laravel facade has built-in method to create own facade and bind it with the app but in background all facade accessor call interface bind method which defined in main service provider container. So i am customising some of the facade which would accelerate application performance

Comment: no the facade class does not have a built in method to bind it with the app, facades are not bound to the container, they are static proxies for other classes/instances that "may" be bound to the container  ... though I still have no idea why you think you need to rewrite something like this, use the application container that laravel provides and learn how it works

Comment: Thanks @lagbox, i didnt say that facade has and builtin method. I said I want to resolve if pattern match found in my container bind method but as i don't have other default facade i cannot push my custom facade into provider container.coz  static::$app always null

Comment: you don't push a facade any where, they are not bound to the container in any way  .... what "default" facade? ... you are going down the wrong path, use what Laravel provides and move on ... what even is this `Application` you are referencing? in Laravel the Application "Container" extends from Container, it is the container

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Let me do more research on it coz my data mapper ORM works in a same way but when I call ORM static::$app initialize and relationship works

Comment: Btw, Thanks @lagbox for having such a nice discussion

Comment: `static::$app` is always going to be `null` until you set it to a value ... in Laravel the Kernels define bootstrappers like `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades` for the Container to run which sets that variable: `Facade::setFacadeApplication($app);` ... this is why you can't just rewrite this stuff without understanding how the Application container works and what it does (especially during bootstrapping) as there is a lot of things going on (the "automagic" of Laravel) ... good luck and have fun

Comment: oh, I missed out this. Thanks @lagbox its really helpful.

Comment: np, updated that last comment as the Kernel's define that bootstrapper for the Container to run ... lots of little moving parts, I would try to walk through the bootstrap process of Laravel itself to see how things interact with the container which would give you a lot of insight into when and how different pieces come into play (not saying that is an easy process to figure out, but it will get easier as you go through it `:)`)

Comment: its really nice @lagbox, but i am only concerned coz bootstrap/app.php is the part of the framework. and Facade is the part of core so i don't think that we required it while we are using phpunit. but let me clarify this one through research. and let me also get more clear insight on it.

Comment: Thanks @lagbox - I have found the solution i have customised the Routes. and also added custom route methods to convert long Route url into short url. why i did that because i don't want to install other package within my system so i have modified core component. so the `shorturl()` method is available within core and its available for whole application.